# Не стандарт для css: второй  p на последней строчке первого  p

Tags: css3, joomla, html, html5, css

Есть код, выводит список статей (тема, часть текста, "подробнее..."),
никак не получается сделать так чтобы слово "Подробнее..." было на последней строчке самого текста статьи.
Исправить код нельзя (или можно, но это дремучие дебри Joomla)
Пробовал float left , и прочие советы из гугла.
Идеально если решится только css  стилями.

---

поясняю: "подробнее..." должно быть после последнего символа последней строки, по сути продолжать первый абзац.

```
<article>   
       <h2>Тема</h2>
       <p>Текст пять шесть строк</p>
       <p class="readmore">
          <a href="/">Подробнее...</a>
       </p>
       <div class='clear_left'></div>
    </article>
```

Comment: p - блочный элемент, поэтому p.readmore необходимо находиться внутри предыдущего p, чтобы оказаться на последней строчке. Поднять можно и с помощью отрицательно margin-top, но вот откалибровать по последней букве так не получится.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/a22XW/

Comment: код менять не получаеться, я знаю что так проще

Comment: тогда такой вариант http://jsfiddle.net/X6CvY/

Comment: так получаеться что "подробнее.." в правом нижнем углу -  что не всегда равно концу последней строки. Правильно вот так: http://jsfiddle.net/XC3VP/ но куда делся этот ответ (я его принял), я не знаю

Comment: @shilgen, я его удалил, потому что он не решал проблему (см. мой комментарий под вопросом). Хотя если вы хотели именно так, а я вас неправильно понял, то и отлично.

Comment: @fike да ваш ответ помог решить проблему. Спасибо вам.